# How to Implement a VoIP Auto (speech) Dialler

Tags: windows, software-rec, voip, sip

Can anyone suggest/recommend a way to implement a speech dialler using a SIP VoIP service?  The software/VoIP equivalent of [this](http://www.pyronix.com/v2gsm-speech-dialler.php)

I want to dial out and play a pre-recorded message as part of an alarm system in response to some event.  This would be running from a Windows server, so ideal solution would probably be a command line exe that takes SIP account details, number to be dialled, audio file name for the message etc. as arguments.  IVR would be a big bonus, so the call receipient can acknowledge receipt by pressing 1 etc.  This is the only way to tell if a call has been answered by voice mail or a real person, I think.  The solution needs to be free or low cost, not hundreds of dollars.

I can find only expensive software packages that are designed for illegal or nuisance robo calls and I do not want to support any solution that is designed for such purpose.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [sipcli](http://www.yasinkaplan.com/SipCli/) which seems to do everything I need.  It's a bit buggy, but the author is responsive.

This is a VoIP client that runs from the command line and can use configuration files or command line arguments and can also run "scenario" files for IVR functionality.

Answer (score -2):

I am using SIP softphone using VoIP software. You can not use this not only in window phones but also for android, iphone and blackberry also. I will personally recommend you this [VoIP Software](http://www.revesoft.com/) and i am sure it will help you to implement a VoIP Auto (speech) Dialler.

Comment: Please edit your answer to meet the [guidelines for recommending software](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).

Comment: The question is asking for software that runs on a Wndows server, not a phone.